# How to set a full HTML page text string in HTML component?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm using the AIR [HTML control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) and I want to pass in a full HTML page string. A full HTML page simply meaning that the HTML markup has HTML begin and end tags. It looks like [htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html#htmlText) property accepts HTML formatted markup but might not be built to accept a full HTML page. A HTML formatted markup would be something like this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph. Here is <b>bold</b> text.</p>
```

Here is a full HTML page example:

```
<html>
   <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Or would it be better to write the page to the file system and then load it through the [location](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html#location) property? One thing to note is that I could be updating the HTML page a lot so I would like to avoid writing to the file system if possible.

Comment: There are better components to display html, do you have to stick with that one?

Comment: @BotMaster You mean like StageWebView? I think that uses the system browser correct? So a Mac user using Firefox will see the view with Firefox and a Windows users using Internet Explorer will see the content with Internet Explorer. The problem with using that is the rendering will be different between those two. I might eventually target StageWebView but it would require much more work to get it working. Also, what ones were you talking about?

Comment: StgaeWebView is one and you can choose if it uses the system browser or embedded web kit. HTMLLoader and FlexHTMLLoader are others.